# Excel 2013 VBA: Changed behaviour of UBound when array is empty

Tags: excel, vba

After hours of testing, I found out that UBound behaves differently in Excel 2013 and Excel 2010 when the array is empty: in Excel 2010, Ubound(EmptyArray) results in 0, whereas in Excel 2013 I get a "Subscript out of Range" Error (which actually is what I would expect).

Can anyone confirm this change in behaviour?

Thank you,

Best regards,

Alexander

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that `UBound` raises the runtime error 9 "Subscript out of Range" on an empty array in all Excel versions from 95 to 2016.

If it doesn't for you, it's either not the `UBound` function you're calling (is it blue in the source code?) or the array is not empty.

There is a slim chance that an Office VBA bug was introduced at some point in v2010 and was promptly fixed, but I am not aware of it.

Comment: Thank you GSerg for your time and answer! Unfortunately, as mentioned, I made a mistake, the array indeed was not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am so sorry.... I should have made a break before I posted the question... I found out that the array was not empty. It's not an excuse that this was well hidden, still I wanted to mention...

Sorry again!